# What are the gaps in a stencil called?

Tags: typography, terminology, lettering

To be useful as stencils, stencil letters usually have cuts in letter forms to hold the interior spaces in place.

Is there are name for these cuts?

[image: Stencil letter 'A' with gaps highlighted]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That part is called the bridge. It connects areas that are cut out or sometimes called an island. The bridges are a thin piece of material that wouldn't be cut out.

Comment: Also "peninsula"?